# Change class attributes based on :not() css selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have one issue with css classes.
I have `.navigation__container` and `.controlBar__container` that I want to display only when my player is having specific set of classes.

I need to display both when user is active. So from Video.js player I have extracted required classes and it looks like this
`.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-user-active .vjs-active .vjs-paused`
My goal here is to hide my container classes when my player is in active state.
I was trying to do this with css `:not()`

```css
.vjs-user-inactive:not(.vjs-paused) {
  .playerNavigation__container,
  .playerControlBar__container {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
}
```

But this is not changing my opacity and display as wanted.
Any suggestions?
Here ar my container classes

```css
.playerNavigation__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.6rem;
  left: 1.8rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}

.playerControlBar__container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: you are in scss, not css, right ?

Comment: yeah this is scss

Comment: Did you try something like: `div.vjs-user-inactive.vjs-user-active.vjs-active:not(.vjs-paused)` ?

Comment: nope. But i know from my frineds code that such solution should work :/

Comment: Provide html then.

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre] with questions like this. Asking us why your CSS doesn't do what you want it to, without showing us what HTML it is supposed to apply to, is pretty pointless.

Comment: _"But this is not changing my opacity and display as wanted."_ - `display:none` will hide these elements immediately, once this rule applies. You can try and transition the opacity all you like, you won't see any effect of that.